# Processing loaded fragment

Tags: jakarta-ee, thymeleaf

I have little bit specific question for loading fragments.

We dynamically load fragments in our forms framework, which generate forms with Java reflection just from form bean definition. Thing is that loaded fragment is processed (don't know why), after closing form tag is processed (`</form>`). Because we carry form context only from opening to closing tag of selected form (because more forms could be on same page), exception is occurring, while processing of loaded fragments is postponed by thymeleaf.

Code for loading fragments:

```
public static List<Node> loadFragment(Arguments arguments, String fragmentName, String fragmentPath) { 
        IFragmentSpec fragmentSpec = new ElementAndAttributeNameFragmentSpec(null, "th:fragment", fragmentName, true); 
        FragmentAndTarget fat = new FragmentAndTarget(fragmentPath, fragmentSpec); 
        return fat.extractFragment(arguments.getConfiguration(), arguments, arguments.getTemplateRepository()); 
}
```

This code is called in `InitializerElProcessor`, where whole form is builded to html. 
Fragment is loaded as it should be, but it's not processed by thymeleaf. How to load fragment already processed by thymeleaf? Or how should we force thymeleaf to process this nodes (result of loading) immediately?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it after hours of debugging..
When I do extract fragment content and append it to current processed element in DOM tree, all new nested nodes are skipped (better, first node is skipped and with that node, all its children are skipped as well). When traversing continues (point 4.), this part of code is processed in `Node` class:

```
void processNode(final Arguments arguments, final boolean processTextNodes, final boolean processCommentNodes) { 
    // some code 
    if (!isPrecomputed()) { 
        precomputeNode(arguments.getConfiguration()); 
    } 

    if (!isSkippable()) { 
            // processing itself 
            ... 

            // move processing to children, but does not happend if node is marked as skippable 
            doAdditionalProcess(executionArguments, executionArguments.getProcessTextNodes(), executionArguments.getProcessCommentNodes()); 
    } 
}
```

Because nodes extracted from fragment are not marked as `precomputed`, `precomputeNode` method follows:

```
final void precomputeNode(final Configuration configuration) { 
    if (!isPrecomputed()) { 
        this.processors = configuration.computeProcessorsForNode(this); 
        if (this.processors == null || this.processors.size() == 0) { 
            this.skippable = true; 
        } else { 
            unsafeSetSkippable(false); 
        } 
            setPrecomputed(true); 
    } 
    doAdditionalPrecomputeNode(configuration); 
}
```

Because node is not marked as `precomputed`, method `computeProcessorsForNode()` is called. This method returns `null`, then node is marked as `skippable`. As comment says, siblings of current node should set this node back as non-skippable in `doAdditionalPrecomputeNode()` method. *Unfortunately this does not happen.*

After some more debugging I've found, that on all extracted nodes from fragment have to be called method `node.setProcessable(true);` to avoid first node to be set as `skippable`. 
I still don't know if this is a bug or feature..